# How to remove leading zero(s) from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim, coalesce

I want to remove leading zeros from SQL table. I'm joining 3 column as one column. 
example

```
col1         col2        col3
00000        S           Gaskin Road
             N           Broad Street
00001                    John Rolfe Road
```

what i want the result to be:

```
1 0 S Gaskin Road or just S Gaskin Road 
2   N Broad Street 
3 1 John Rolfe Road
```

here is the script that i join 3 column

```
   ,COALESCE(CASE WHEN col1 = '' THEN '' ELSE col1 + ' ' END, '')  + 
   COALESCE(CASE WHEN col2 = '' THEN '' ELSE col2 + ' ' END, '')  + 
   COALESCE(CASE WHEN col3 = '' THEN '' ELSE col3 + ' ' END, '') as allCol
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `col1`?

Comment: Can you just convert it to int? Numbers don't have leading zeros.

Comment: col1(nvarchar(255),null)

Comment: @james you mean change the data type to Int instead of nvarchar?

Comment: I mean just `select convert(col1, int)` -- that will of course not work if you also store something else than numbers there.

Comment: I don't have anything else in col1 one. its all number. all the values i have is empty, 00000 and 00001. i don't know what empty count as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cast` col1 to `int` so the leading zeroes are removed and `cast` the `int` to `varchar` for concatenation.

```
COALESCE(CASE WHEN col1 = '' THEN '' ELSE cast(cast(col1 as int) as varchar(255))+ ' ' END, '')  + 
COALESCE(CASE WHEN col2 = '' THEN '' ELSE col2 + ' ' END, '')  + 
COALESCE(CASE WHEN col3 = '' THEN '' ELSE col3 + ' ' END, '')
```

Comment: @john . . . This works *assuming* that `col1` is always a number.  In my experience with house numbers, that is not a safe assumption.

Answer (score 1):

One method uses `patindex()`.  My first thought on how to write this is:

```
  ((case when col1 is null or col1 = '' or col1 = '000000' then ''
         else substring(col1, patindex('%[^0]%', col1), 6) + ' '
    end) +
   (case when col2 is null or col2 = '' then ''
         else col2 + ' '
    end) +
   (case when col3 is null or col3 = '' then ''
         else col3
    end)
   ) as allcol
```

If you already need to use `case`, I don't see an advantage to mixing in `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own function to remove all the leading zeros :

```
CREATE FUNCTION RemoveLeadingZeros(@value varchar(255)) RETURNS varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
  while substring(@value, 1, 1) = '0' and datalength(@value) > 1 
  begin
    set @value = substring(@value, 2, 255)
  end

  return @value;
END
GO
```

So the concatenation of your 3 fields now will be :

```
,COALESCE(CASE WHEN col1 = '' THEN '' ELSE dbo.RemoveLeadingZeros(col1) + ' ' END, '')  + 
 COALESCE(CASE WHEN col2 = '' THEN '' ELSE col2 + ' ' END, '')  + 
 COALESCE(CASE WHEN col3 = '' THEN '' ELSE col3 + ' ' END, '') as allCol
```

Answer (score 0):

```
COALESCE(CASE WHEN col1 = '' THEN '' ELSE SUBSTRING(col1, PATINDEX('%[^0]%', col1+'.'), LEN(col1))+ ' ' END, '')  + 
COALESCE(CASE WHEN col2 = '' THEN '' ELSE col2 + ' ' END, '')  + 
COALESCE(CASE WHEN col3 = '' THEN '' ELSE col3 + ' ' END, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

For Amazon Redshift:

```
TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM colname)
```